# Code coverage for integration test by jest and nyc always return 0% for statements and lines

Tags: jestjs, integration-testing, code-coverage, ts-jest, nyc

I'm trying to do code coverage for our `Jest` integration tests.
The tests directory is inside some sub-directory inside the server project with standalone `package.jso`n and configurations.
The services and libs that need to cover are located in the main project root directory, that mean outside the tests sub-directory.

When I've tried to it by `nyc` is able to include the required directories outside the tests dir but no real coverage are return in the report.

When I've tried to id by the `--coverage` flag in `Jest`, It's not able to access outside the tests dir, even when adding `rootDir` option inside the configuration file, it just make a mess in the project.

I've also tried to execute `nyc` together with the api-gateway launching and together with the services launching but it didn't change the results as well.

The project architecture is something like the following -->

```
server-project root
  .nyc_output
  _coverage_
  services
  libs
  src
  api-gateway
  test
  - src
   - integration-tests
     -  test.ts
     -  ...
  - jest.config.ts
  - jest-integration.config.ts
  - package.json
  package.json
```

**Related versions:**

```
Node v14.18.1
npm 6.14.15
pnpm 6.9.1

"istanbul-reports": "^3.1.5",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"@types/jest": "^26.0.18",
"@types/node": "13.7.1",
"babel-plugin-istanbul": "^6.1.1",
"nyc": "^15.1.0",
"ts-jest": "^26.4.4",
"ts-node": "^9.1.1",
"typescript": "^4.1.2"
```

The script below contains nyc together with jest - non of them work as expected:

```
"test:integration:coverage": "nyc --cwd='../' --exclude-after-remapjest=false --reporter=lcov --reporter=text pnpm run test:integration -- --coverage --collectCoverageFrom='./../services/**/src/*.ts'",
```

It's located inside `test/package.json` and launchd by `pnpm`

`nyc` configuration inside `package.json` (project root) -->

```
  "nyc": {
    "extends": "@istanbuljs/nyc-config-typescript",
    "require": "@babel/register",
    "check-coverage": true,
    "all": true,
    "cache": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "instrument": true,
    "lines": 90,
    "branches": 90,
    "functions": 90,
    "statements": 90,
    "reporter": [
      "text-summary",
      "lcov",
      "text"
    ],
    "report-dir": "coverage",
    "include": [
      "services/**/src/*.ts",
      "api-gateway/src/*.ts",
      "libs/**/src/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "**/test/**",
      "**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "extension": [
      ".ts",
      ".tsx"
    ],
    "temp-dir": ".nyc_output",
    "excludeNodeModules": true,
    "source-map": true,
    "produce-source-map": true
  }
```

Jest configuration iside `test/jest-integration.config.ts` (extends to the main jest.config.ts file) -->

```
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
const baseConfig = require('./jest.config');
const base = '**/integration-tests/services';
const setupDir = './src/tests/integration-tests/setup';
module.exports = {
  ...baseConfig,
  testMatch: [
    ...[
      'abtests/*.test.ts',
       'moretests/*.test.ts',
  ],
  globalSetup: `${setupDir}/jest-integration-setup.ts`,
  globalTeardown: `${setupDir}/jest-integration-teardown.ts`,
};
```

---

**Output results:**

```
  at src/tests/integration-tests/services/abtests/abtest.test.ts:18:13
```

PASS  src/tests/integration-tests/services/abtests/abtest.test.ts
abtests
✓ abtests params in me query (300 ms)
✓ override existing test (110 ms)
✓ create a new test with value (109 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------

```
    Failed to write coverage reports:
    ERROR: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    STACK: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
at Function.getPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
at Date (/Users/myname/repos/server-project/node_modules/.pnpm/jest-date-mock@1.0.8/node_modules/jest-date-mock/lib/mockDate.js:39:44)
at new HtmlReport (/Users/myname/repos/server-project/node_modules/.pnpm/istanbul-reports@3.0.2/node_modules/istanbul-reports/lib/html/index.js:260:21)
at new LcovReport (/Users/myname/repos/server-project/node_modules/.pnpm/istanbul-reports@3.0.2/node_modules/istanbul-reports/lib/lcov/index.js:14:21)
at Object.create (/Users/myname/repos/server-project/node_modules/.pnpm/istanbul-reports@3.0.2/node_modules/istanbul-reports/index.js:22:16)
at /Users/myname/repos/server-project/node_modules/.pnpm/@jest+reporters@26.6.2/node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/CoverageReporter.js:248:20
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at CoverageReporter.onRunComplete (/Users/myname/repos/server-project/node_modules/.pnpm/@jest+reporters@26.6.2/node_modules/@jest/reporters/build/CoverageReporter.js:240:25)
at ReporterDispatcher.onRunComplete (/Users/myname/repos/server-project/node_modules/.pnpm/@jest+core@26.6.3/node_modules/@jest/core/build/ReporterDispatcher.js:88:9)
at TestScheduler.scheduleTests (/Users/myname/repos/server-project/node_modules/.pnpm/@jest+core@26.6.3/node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:350:5)
at runJest (/Users/myname/repos/server-project/node_modules/.pnpm/@jest+core@26.6.3/node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:376:19)
at _run10000 (/Users/myanme/repos/server-project/node_modules/.pnpm/@jest+core@26.6.3/node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:416:7)
at runCLI (/Users/myname/repos/server-project/node_modules/.pnpm/@jest+core@26.6.3/node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:271:3)
at Object.run (/Users/myname/repos/server-project/node_modules/.pnpm/jest-cli@26.6.3/node_modules/jest-cli/build/cli/index.js:163:37)
```

Test Suites: 2 passed, 2 total
Tests:       1 skipped, 4 passed, 5 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.01 s
Ran all test suites.
 report is created on: /Users/myname/repos/server-project/test/html-report/report.html
ERROR: Coverage for lines (0%) does not meet global threshold (90%)
ERROR: Coverage for functions (0%) does not meet global threshold (90%)
ERROR: Coverage for branches (0%) does not meet global threshold (90%)
ERROR: Coverage for statements (0%) does not meet global threshold (90%)
-----------------------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                                     | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s
-----------------------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files                                |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |
api-gateway/src                         |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |
config.ts                              |       0 |      100 |     100 |       0 | 81
main.ts                                |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 | 11-43
storage.ts                             |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 | 6-19
libs/apollo-federation-tester/src       |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |
index.ts                               |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 | 17-85

Please your help!
Thanks.